# Alarm clock handling on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time, muktzeh

Are you allowed to touch an alarm clock on Shabbos?

Comment: The title of this post does not match the content. Do you want to know about moving it, or simply touching it?

Comment: Why might you not be allowed to touch it? Is there anything that you are not allowed to touch on Shabbat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are allowed to touch an alarm clock on shabas. One may touch anything on shabas that one may touch during chol. ([Rema O.C. 308:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=211))

As explained there, the prohibitions of Muktzah only apply to moving an object, not touching it.

Answer (score 4):

R. Menashe Klein writes in [Mishneh Halachos 11:304](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1883&pgnum=229) that one is allowed to turn off the alarm on a mechanical alarm clock on Shabbos, even while the alarm is sounding. He writes that this is not a problem of "extinguishing", rather it is merely preventing the alarm from ringing more.

(In 13:49 he makes clear he is talking only about mechanical alarm clocks and not electronic ones -- but surprisingly enough there are plenty of wind-up alarm clocks still on the market nowadays)