# Is my dog muktzeh to me on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, animals, muktzeh

I believe that putting a leash on a dog to take it for a walk on Shabbos is permissible, even in a place where there is no eiruv, since the leash is to protect the dog.

What about touching my dog, and as an extension to that, petting it. These are things that can be both beneficial to me and to the well being of the animal.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/playing-with-a-pet-on-shabbos