# Is a Digital Clock muktzeh on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, electricity

This question occurred to me over Shabbos, when my clock fell over. What *Muktzeh* category does a digital alarm clock fall into? If it has a backup battery, does that change anything?

Additionally, if it has a back-light, does that bring it under the same category as a lamp, or is its "lamp" function *"batel"* to its clock function, which may be under a different category of *Muktzeh*?

Comment: If you leave the clock alone, I can't see any problems. I don't follow what you're planning on doing with the clock and what the concern with the backup battery is.

Comment: @DanF To move it back to its upright position, so I can see the time. But it made me curious as to its general *muktzeh* status. The backup battery may itself be *muktzeh*, and if so, possibly make the entire clock a *"basis"* to it.

Comment: This should be relevant [Moving Electrical Appliances on Shabbos](http://dinonline.org/2010/06/03/moving-electrical-appliances-on-shabbos/)

Comment: Why would it be Muktzeh at all? Why is this different from a digital wristwatch that also has a battery? One is allowed to view the time on Shabbos. (Note that I'm assuming this is a standing clock. If it's a clock that hangs on the wall, there is an unrelated issue of hanging stuff on a wall, which is not related to being an electrical appliance i.e. it's forbidden to hang a picture on a wall)

Comment: @Salmononius2 Read the article linked in the comment above yours. That should explain why (at the very least) it *might* be *muktzeh*.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/alarm-clock-handling-on-shabbos